# Springboot MVC - storing measurements

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

Springboot and JPA project with a Java class called `Horse`. Each horse has related class `Health Checks`. Part of a health check includes taking the weight of the horse.

Some places record three weights and average them, some places weigh once. The places that weigh more than once like to keep all the measurements rather than just storing the average.

I would like `HealthCheck` class to be flexible enough to store one or several weight measurements for each Health Check.

I tried:

```
public class HealthCheck {
    private Long id;
    private List<Integer> weight;
```

But then the IDE complains `basic attribute type should not be a container`. Does this mean I need to create a weight class?

Q: What is the correct way to store several measurements for weight?

Note most places either do 1 weight measurement or 3 measurements (with an average) per horse, but a list seemed to provide the most flexibility.

Comment: i think `basic attribute type should not be a container` would be for `Long id` instead of list

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `HealthCheck` is a JPA entity. If so, you can’t store a list (container) of integers in a single column so you need to tell JPA how to map it. You probably want `@ElementCollection` as the integers in the list are not entities (they are basic) so `@OneToMany` is not appropriate.